# prestashop 1.6:how to write insert query in ajax.php

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am just working prestashop in insert query.Below i have attached my ajax file.I have include all supported file but dataes is not inserted in this table.I don't know what is error?.Kindly check and help me.

```
include '../../config/settings.inc.php';
include '../../config/defines.inc.php';
include '../../config/config.inc.php';

    $api=$_REQUEST['api_key'];
    $install=$_REQUEST['installtion_id'];
    $percentages=$_REQUEST['dep_per'];
    $package=$_REQUEST['dep_plan'];


       $res = Db::getInstance()->insert('pay4later_setting',array(
        'api_key'       => '$api', 
        'installtion_id'      => '$install',
        'deposite_percentage' =>'$percentages',
         'package_plan' =>'$package',
    ));
```

Comment: you only need to include (or require_once) the config.inc.php, it will take care of the rest needed files. also, are you sure the vars have the correct value? is there a key constraint in the table?

Comment: ya,I am already tried only include config.inc.php,and my values are very correct.Still not inserted

Answer (score 0):

Where did you kept your ajax request.Ok,No problem.

For example,

In prestashop i have sent my ajax request through configure.tpl file

**configure.tpl**

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit_label').click(function(){
               var data = "welcome";
                $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                url:baseDir+'modules/anything/data.php',
                data:{
                ajax:true,
                name:data,
                },
                success: function(html){

                    if(html.added)
                    {
                         $("#success").html(html.added);

                    }


            } 
                });

        });

});
```

And here i have using data.php as a php file

**data.php**

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $label_name = $_POST['name']; or you can use Tools::getValue("name");

    $connect_db = Db::getInstance()->insert('label', array(
    'label_name' => pSQL($label_name),
    ));

    $getin['added'] = 'Label created successfully';//here we have using JSON datatype so we need to create object and store some values.

    echo json_encode($getin);


}
```

Thanks & Regards,
krishna.